# Google sheets, IMPORTRANGE and strip first character

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am importing data from another sheet using a range:

`=IMPORTRANGE("url", "tab!C5:JT10")`

But the data has the "€" symbol in front. So i want to combine the `IMPORTRANGE` function above with this function:

`=RIGHT(A2, LEN(A2)-1)` to strip that character. How could I do it please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all the data that you are importing has "€" in front then use this formula:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(IMPORTRANGE("url", "tab!C5:JT10"), "€", ""))`